# Relative height based on wrapped text

Tags: android, android-xml

The `Title` in the screenshot is updated asynchronously and can be 2-3 lines. That means it should push the dummy text bellow. However I have a placeholder on the right for an image which makes things more complicated.

**I want the dummy lengthy text to be pushed based on either the image or the text on the top-left.** What can be a good structure?

Currently in my code if I update the title asynchronously it pushes the `name`, `address` and `12:00` but not the big text. These 4 textview are hidden below the big one if they overflow.

[image]

I know it's messy but the layout is:

```
-RelativeLayout
  -Scrollview
      -Linearlayout (vertical)
         -Linearlayout
            -Linearlayout(vertical)
               -The 4 textviews
            -Image
         -Textview with big dummy text
```

And here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".EventDisplay" >

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.74" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="178dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="7.03"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/venueName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="name"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventAddress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="address"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventStartTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:text="12:00"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
                    android:maxHeight="100dp"
                    android:maxWidth="100dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventDescription"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_weight="8.55"
                android:text="When the action bar hides, the system adjusts your layout to fill the screen space now available. You can bring the action bar back by calling show().When the action bar hides, the system adjusts your layout to fill the screen space now available. You can bring the action bar back by calling show().When the action bar hides, the system adjusts your layout to fill the screen space now available. You can bring the action bar back by calling show().When the action bar hides, the system adjusts your layout to fill the screen space now available. You can bring the action bar back by calling show().When the action bar hides, the system adjusts your layout to fill the screen space now available. You can bring the action bar back by calling show().When the action bar hides, the system adjusts your layout to fill the screen space now available. You can bring the action bar back by calling show().When the action bar hides, the system adjusts your layout to fill the screen space now available. You can bring the action bar back by calling show().When the action bar hides, the system adjusts your layout to fill the screen space now available. You can bring the action bar back by calling show().When the action bar hides, the system adjusts your layout to fill the screen space now available. You can bring the action bar back by calling show()." />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Another idea that I had was to put a margin equal to the image's size (e.g. 100dp) on the LinearLayout (which wraps the 4 textviews). However even if I have negative margin on the image (-100dp) to bring it back on the left, it does not.

Ps: Unfortunately defying the linearlayout which wraps the title with fixed width is not helpful since we have to care for many devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

I posted only the particular `LinearLayout`

```
         <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.74" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/venueName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="name"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventAddress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="address"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventStartTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:text="12:00"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="@color/darkGrey"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Or Instead if using`LinearLayout` use `RelativeLayout`

```
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.74" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/venueName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="name"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventAddress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="address"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventStartTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:text="12:00"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@color/darkGrey" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```